# How to search local commit GIT

Tags: git, github, version-control

Can someone help me to retrieve my commit?
i cannot find my commit anywhere

here's what i do

1. i'm in the branch master
2. i move to my previous commit in the branch master(so now i'm in nowhere branch)
3. type some changes
4. commit and push
5. got an error because i cannot push commit in nowhere branch
6. i move to branch master
7. now my last commit gone

any idea to retrieve my previous commit?

I've tried to use git log but still can't find my last commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `git reflog` to search the commit you want by the ref log message.

Comment: @user3635111 A better way to avoid such problem is to create a branch from that previous commit and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pushed the commit to nowhere branch, you can not see the commit in master branch.
You have to merge/cherrypick the commit to your master branch. Then you can push the commit from the master branch.

```
(nowhere)$ git merge master
(resolve any merge conflicts if there are any)
git checkout master
git merge development (there shouldn't be any conflicts now)
git push
```